# Can I pass a function object to angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

My problem is the following: I'd like to write a custom directive that works like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="prefix" prettified="angular.lowercase">
<input type="text" ng-model="firstName" prettified="capitalize">
<input type="text" ng-model="abbreviation" prettified="addDot">
```

where `capitalize` is a function of scope:

```
$scope.capitalize = function(value) {
  return capitalizedValue;
}
```

But `attrs.prettified` seems to be interpreted always as string in the directive.
How can I change that?

**UPDATE**

the directive looks like this:

```
.directive('prettified', function () {
      return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          prettified: '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

          ngModel.$formatters.push(attrs.prettified);
        }
      };
    });
```

**UPDATE 2**

It is important that I want to change the model along with the view.

Comment: Directive code please?

Answer (score 1):

You `$scope.capitalize` should be available trough `scope.prettified`, not in attributes.

Comment: If it is a function, scope.prettified() seems to return the function object itself, but for some reason $formatters.push does not accept it.

Comment: Ah, I just now realized what you want to do.. try `<input type="text" ng-model="firstName" prettified="capitalize()">` it will execute `capitalize()` function and set attribute value to what `capitalize()` returns.

Comment: But then `capitalize` would be executed only once right?

Comment: Well, yes. You only call it once, so it will be executed once.

Comment: No. It needs to be executed as many times the user changes the input field. That is why the function is passed to the formatter and not its result.

Comment: Then you need take a difference approach, you should `$scope.$watch` ngModel value, and call that function every time you need it. When passing function (or something) in directive attribute, it is executed only once (when it's compiled)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a filter instead?

```
myApp.filter('capitalize', function() {
    return function(input) {
        //do whatever you want to do with input
        var str = input.split('');
        str[0].toUpperCase();
        str.join('');
        return str;
    }
});
myApp.filter('lowerCase', function() {
    return function(input) {
        //do whatever you want to do with input
        input = ...
        return input;
    }
});
myApp.filter('addDot', function() {
    return function(input) {
        //do whatever you want to do with input
        input = ...
        return input;
    }
});
```

and on your view you can use the filter like:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="prefix | lowerCase" >
<input type="text" ng-model="firstName | cappitalize">
<input type="text" ng-model="abbreviation | addDot">
```

There's more you can do with filters and it is a really powerful resource of AngularJS.

Have a look at the documentation for further information on filters
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

And also on this video:
https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-filters

In fact, I would recommend all of egghead.io videos. They are of great help indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't use filters because filters don't change the model.

Comment: In that case, you will need to use compile or a onChange event, but it will increase the complexity of your code. Using compile, you can still use filters by using the $filter('nameOfFilter') sintaxe on your directive, rather than having a method inside of your controller - which limits the functionality to only elements in the scope of that controller... Filters are the best thing if you want to make your functions reusable or if they repeat a lot throughout your code... Have a look at this video, it might help you understand the idea: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-angular-element

Comment: Sorry Dude, you're completely misunderstanding the question.

Comment: I don't think I am misunderstanding you, but if I am, I apologize. I'm reading this thread as well as domakas' answer thread. I can see that it has been pointed out the use of $watch. Have you watched the video egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-angular-element I posted on the last reply? It shows you briefly how to use compile and $watch so you can adapt to your needs. But I will stop here. Cheers for the negative mark.